# How to verify PayPal Webhooks in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I found some old answers dealing with PHP and [this code example](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/notifications/webhook-events/webhook_payload_verify.js), but I am not sure whether this is outdated now since the repo is archived and I know that generally PayPal moved to an approach that just uses the REST API.

I would love if somebody could give an update here on whats the latest recommendation is and whether the code here from 2015 is outdated now.

```js
/* Copyright 2015-2016 PayPal, Inc. */
"use strict";

var paypal = require('../../../');
require('../../configure');

// Sends the webhook event data to PayPal to verify the webhook event signature is correct and 
// the event data came from PayPal.

// Note this sample is only for illustrative purposes. You must have a valid webhook configured with your
// client ID and secret. This sample may not work due to other tests deleting and creating webhooks.

// Normally, you would pass all the HTTP request headers sent in the Webhook Event, but creating a
// JSON object here for the sample.
var certURL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-a5cafa77";
var transmissionId = "103e3700-8b0c-11e6-8695-6b62a8a99ac4";
var transmissionSignature = "t8hlRk64rpEImZMKqgtp5dlWaT1W8ed/mf8Msos341QInVn3BMQubjAhM/cKiSJtW07VwJvSX7X4+YUmHBrm5BQ+CEkClke4Yf4ouhCK6GWsfs0J8cKkmjI0XxfJpPLgjROEWY3MXorwCtbvrEo5vrRI2+TyLkquBKAlM95LbNWG43lxMu0LHzsSRUBDdt5IP1b2CKqbcEJKGrC78iw+fJEQGagkJAiv3Qvpw8F/8q7FCQAZ3c81mzTvP4ZH3Xk2/nNznEA7eMi3u1EjSpTmLfAb423ytX37Ts0QpmPNgxJe8wnMB/+fvt4xjYH6KNe+bIcYU30hUIe9O8c9UFwKuQ==";
var transmissionTimestamp = "2016-10-05T14:57:40Z";
var headers = {
    'paypal-auth-algo': 'SHA256withRSA',
    'paypal-cert-url': certURL,
    'paypal-transmission-id': transmissionId,
    'paypal-transmission-sig': transmissionSignature,
    'paypal-transmission-time': transmissionTimestamp
};

// The eventBody parameter is the entire webhook event body.
var eventBody = '{"id":"WH-82L71649W50323023-5WC64761VS637831A","event_version":"1.0","create_time":"2016-10-05T14:57:40Z","resource_type":"sale","event_type":"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED","summary":"Payment completed for $ 6.01 USD","resource":{"id":"8RS6210148826604N","state":"completed","amount":{"total":"6.01","currency":"USD","details":{"subtotal":"3.00","tax":"0.01","shipping":"1.00","handling_fee":"2.00","shipping_discount":"3.00"}},"payment_mode":"INSTANT_TRANSFER","protection_eligibility":"ELIGIBLE","protection_eligibility_type":"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE","transaction_fee":{"value":"0.47","currency":"USD"},"invoice_number":"","custom":"Hello World!","parent_payment":"PAY-11X29866PC6848407K72RIQA","create_time":"2016-10-05T14:57:18Z","update_time":"2016-10-05T14:57:26Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8RS6210148826604N","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8RS6210148826604N/refund","rel":"refund","method":"POST"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-11X29866PC6848407K72RIQA","rel":"parent_payment","method":"GET"}]},"links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-82L71649W50323023-5WC64761VS637831A","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-82L71649W50323023-5WC64761VS637831A/resend","rel":"resend","method":"POST"}]}';

// The webhookId is the ID of the configured webhook (can find this in the PayPal Developer Dashboard or
// by doing a paypal.webhook.list()
var webhookId = "3TR748995U920805P";

paypal.notification.webhookEvent.verify(headers, eventBody, webhookId, function (error, response) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log(response);

        // Verification status must be SUCCESS
        if (response.verification_status === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("It was a success.");
        } else {
            console.log("It was a failed verification");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those SDKs are abstractions for the REST API but are no longer being maintained, so it is best not to use them.

There are two possible ways to verify Webhooks

1. Posting the message back to PayPal with the [verify webhook sygnature](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post) REST API call. You'll need to use a client_id and secret get an access token first, same as all other REST API calls.
2. Verifying the cryptographic signature yourself ([Java pseudocode here](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#link-eventheadervalidation)).

For either method, the "webhookId" -- as opposed to each webhook *event* id -- is 17 alphadigits and for security (anti-spoof) reasons not part of the Webhook message itself (you get it when registering for webhooks or reviewing existing subscribed hooks in the [REST app config](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications))

---

As it can sometimes be a point of confusion, it's worth mentioning that verifying webhooks is for your own information -- to confirm the message did in fact originate from PayPal, and not some other (malicious) actor.

But for PayPal itself to consider the webhook message successfully delivered (and not keep retrying), all that needs to happen is for the listener URL it's posted to to respond with an HTTP 200 OK status. That concludes the webhook message delivery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought! I am trying to go for 1). I am right now sending back the headers in sandbox mode, but I am not sure what to send back for `webhook_id` and `webhook_event` in sandbox mode?

Comment: The webhook id is from subscribing to webhooks. You can view it in the REST App.  The webhook event is the entire payload body of the webhook message you are trying to verify

Comment: Do you know if I can get those in sandbox mode? It says here that simulator generated events cannot be verified? Does this mean that testing my webhooks won't be possible unless in production or am I missing something? https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/simulator/#link-simulatorqueuestheevent

Comment: Simulator events -- ones sent by the simulator -- cannot be verified. You can subscribe to webhook events for a sandbox app.